NaviagtionMixin within Child Component or Lightning Modal Links to JavaScript Void
When using a lighting modal or child component using NavigationMixin and lightning navigation, GenerateUrl does not work it seems. The result in the promise returns null. Example test code I used within a parent component that demonstrates the result. Not sure if this is designed behavior or not. This solution is not applicable in my instance I believe. Thanks in advance.
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";
import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";
const TARGET_BLANK = "_blank";
export default class GetRecordPageUrl extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId;
    @api label;
    @api target = TARGET_BLANK;
    @api state;
    @api replaceCurrentPage = false;
    url;

    connectedCallback() {
        const recordPageRef = {
            type: "standard__recordPage",
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.recordId,
                actionName: "view"
            }
        };
        if (this.state) {
            recordPageRef.state = this.state;
        }
        this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl](recordPageRef, 
            this.replaceCurrentPage).then((url) => {
            this.url = url;
        });
    }
}

<template>
    <a target={target} href={url} title={label}>{label}</a>
</template>


There's a few questions floating around for pretty much the same problem.
For whatever reason the NavigationMixin doesn't work within LWCs that extend LightningElement.
The workaround I've had to use is to just hard code the URL.
e.g.
this.url = `/lightning/r/${this.recordId}/view`;


Thanks. That's what I'm doing in the interim as well. I'm going to try a few more things to check.
